# Ripping video links out of HTML pages using Python

Tags: python, html-parsing

I have a bunch of HTML pages with video players embedded in them, via various different HTML tags, using the `<video>` tag, but also other ones too. What's uniting in common all of these different approaches to holding video files, is that they are links to various common video websites, such as

- YouTube
- Rumble
- Bitchute
- Brighteon
- Odysee
- Vimeo
- Dailymotion

Content videos originating from different video hosting websites may have different ways of embedding the videos. For example, they may or may not use the `<video>` tag.

Correction, I am not dealing with a bunch of websites, I am dealing with a bunch of HTML pages stored locally. I want to use Python to rip the links to these videos from the HTML pages, and save them into some json file, which could be later read and thrown into `youtube-dl` for downloading all these videos.

My question is, how exactly would I go about doing this? What kind of strategy should I pursue? Should I just attempt to read the HTML file as a plain text file using Python, and then use some kind of algorithm or regular expression to look for links to these video hosting websites. If that is the case, then I am bad at regular expressions, and would like some assistance about how to find links to the video websites in the text using regular expressions in Python.

Alternatively, I could potentially make use of HTML's DOM structure. I do not know if this is possible to do in Python or not, but basically to read the HTML not as a simple text file, but as a DOM tree, and traversing up and down the tree to specifically pick up only the tags that have the videos embedded in them. I do not know how to do that either.

I guess, what I'm trying to say here is, I first need some kind of strategy to achieve my big goal in mind, and then I actually need to know what kind of code or APIs do I need to use in order to achieve my goal, or ripping out links to video files out of the HTML, and saving them somewhere.

Comment: You could look into web scraping with Python - I think that could accomplish what you're looking for

The link below may help in getting started

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-scrape-videos-using-python/

Comment: @jrynes I am not processing a web page on the internet, I am parsing HTML documents stored on a local file system.